# How to update document text of WebBrowser control after adding elements?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

In form load i have this line of code

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<table id='table1'><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>";
```

On button click Iam having these lines of code that adds new row of table.
But in message box changes are is not reflected. Should I manually update the webbrowser content like document text. If so how to do it?

```
    HtmlElement element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("table1");
    HtmlElement mTBody = element.FirstChild;
    HtmlElement mTR = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("tr");
    HtmlElement mTD1 = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("td");

    mTD1.InnerText = "Teamviewer Id1";
    mTD1.SetAttribute("id", "TeamviewerId1");

    mTR.AppendChild(mTD1);
    mTBody.AppendChild(mTR);

    MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
```

Answer (score 0):

The content is fetched asynchronously from the web browser.

Try subscribing to the `DocumentCompleted` event and then showing the `DocumentText` from there.

**Option 1**

Refresh your web browser after addding in the elements:

```
webBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely);
```

Then get the `DoucmentText` from the `DocumentCompleted` event

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sender.DocumentText);
}
```

**Option 2**

If the above option didn't work or didn't fire the `DoucmentCompleted` event.

Try navigating to your url after adding the elements on the button click event.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(url); //Instead of the refresh
```

Then in your `DocumentCompleted` event, check that the URL matches (as having multiple frames will fire the DocumentCompleted event multiple times) then display your DocumentText

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.Equals(webBrowser1.Url)) {
            MessageBox.Show(sender.DocumentText);
        }
    }
```

Comment: here webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted event is firing only at first load. It is not firing after adding dynamic elements to it.

Comment: Maybe try refreshing the web browser control after adding in the elements. See my updated answer

Comment: No, both methods are not working. It is working only when I am writing this line webBrowser1.DocumentText = element.OuterHtml.ToString(); after adding elements. Doing it manually may be because I am refering table using HtmlElement as local object. But if so how the changes are shown in the webbrowser control.

Comment: Yeah i'm not too sure then. All i know is that the DocumentText is only set on the DocumentCompleted event, which may be different to what the DOM is displaying.
If you can get the DoucmentCompleted event to be hit after you've added the elements, then the DocumentText should be correct